# How to get a recuring parts from a file in php

Tags: php

I have a file file.txt. This file has portions and parts that recur throughout the file. I 
am trying to read the parts between the last and the first key words.

I have managed to get the first and the last key words but I can't read the lines between the key words.

Here is my script

```
$file=file('file.txt');
    $begin = 'first_line';
    $end='last_line';
    foreach ($file as $lineNumber => $line) {
            $lineNumber++;
            if (strpos($line,$begin)) 
            {
            echo $lineNumber.$line."<br/>";
            }
            elseif (strpos($line,$end))
            {
            echo $value."<br/>";
            }
            echo $lineNumber. $line."<br/>";
            }
```

Please some one assist me.

Comment: Can you provide an example input file so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$file = file('file.txt');

$begin = 'first_line';
$end = 'last_line';

$isInside = false;
foreach ($file as $lineNumber => $line) 
{
    $lineNumber++;

    if (!(strpos($line,$begin)===false)) 
        $isInside = true;

    if ($isInside)
        echo $lineNumber." : ".$line."<br/>";

    if (!(strpos($line,$end)===false))
        $isInside = false;

}
```

Some points:

- You were displaying everything regardless, my script only shows lines between $begin and $end.
- Your comparison is case-sensitive
- You had a major bug using `strpos` and assuming it returns true if it matches. It could also return `0` if the string matches at the beginning,hence using `===` to catch this. See the disclaimer on the [strpos page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: @user731144 No problem - would you mind closing the question? (just click the green tick next to the answer) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
    $lines=file('data.txt');
$begin = 'first_line';
$end='last_line';

$switch = false;
$content = "";
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $begin) !== false) {$switch = true;continue;}
    if(strpos($line, $end) !== false) $switch = false;
    if(!$switch) continue;
    $content .= "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.. this also is accomplishing what i wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
$file=fopen("welcome.txt","r");
while(!feof($file))
 {
    $open=fgets($file);
    print $open;
 }
 fclose($file);
```